# In C++ how do you define ***.h for class?

Tags: c++

I have 3 files: ***.cpp *2 and ***.h *1

once i put into terminal: g++ mymain.cpp landowner.cpp -o mymain
it says

> error: ‘landowner’ was not declared in this scope
> 8 |   landowner Alex;
> |   ^~~~~~~~~

```
//landowner.h

#ifndef LANDOWNER
#define LANDOWNER

using namespace std;

void ShowScore();

#endif
```

```
//landowner.cpp
#include "landowner.h"
#include <iostream>
class landowner
{
private:
  string name;
  long score;
  int cards[20];
public:
  landowner(){}
  ~landowner(){}

  void ShowScore(){
    cout<<name<<"current score："<<score<<endl;
  }
  
protected:
  
  
};
```

```
//mymain.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "landowner.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

  landowner Alex;
  Alex.name = Alex;
  Alex.score = 100;

  Alex.ShowScore();
  
  return 0;
}
```

which is very confusing. i must have missed something.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class decparation should be placed inside the header.

```
//landowner.h

#ifndef LANDOWNER
#define LANDOWNER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void ShowScore();

class landowner
{
private:
  string name;
  long score;
  int cards[20];
public:
  landowner(){}
  ~landowner(){}

  void ShowScore(){
    cout<<name<<"current score："<<score<<endl;
  }
  
protected:
  
  
};

#endif
```

```
//landowner.cpp
#include "landowner.h"

// currently we have nothing to implement here
```

Using `using namespace std;` (especially in headers) is bad, so it should be removed and the rest part of code should be changed.

[c++ - Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. That helped me a lot!!!